# python selenium: clicking buttons with various html element/css attributes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

i'm trying to create python automation scripts using selenium to make appointment times, however i'm having some trouble with clicking on certain elements. to confirm an appointment the steps are going to the webpage > selecting the date > selecting the time > hitting confirm

this is what i've got so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('<url.date>') -- this works

driver.find_element(By.ID,'corresponding time id').click() -- this works

driver.find_element(By.DATA-TEST-ID,'order_summary_page-button-book').click() -- this is where i'm struggling
```

i've also tried doing it by the button class, using the css selector and looking for 'Reserve Now' text, and using the xpath

- when i do it by xpath, i get the error `NoSuchElementException`

i tried adding a webdriver wait function but that didn't seem to work either.
the appointment times are really hard to get, so i'd rather not but any wait times into the code so it can execute and book as soon as slots open

here are the elements:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S62kR.png

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please share all your code including the link. Otherwise this question is missing minimal debugging details

Answer (score 0):

Selenium doesn't have option to identify the element by `DATA-TEST-ID` locator.

In this case You have to use either by `xpath` or `css selector`

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//button[@data-test-id="order_summary_page-button-book"]').click()
```

OR

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button[data-test-id="order_summary_page-button-book"]').click()
```

---

Ideally you should use explicit wait to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-test-id="order_summary_page-button-book"]'))).click()
```

you need following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: the first two (xpath and css_selector) give me `NoSuchElementException`. using webdriverwait errors out to `NoSuchWindowException`

Comment: @shellyisrani: the answer I have provided based on the screenshot, In that case you need to share the url to investigate the issue.